# Drush won't clear uploaded temporary files

Tags: 7, drush, files

So, working on a unix system, it's common that /tmp has the sticky bit set (i.e. only the owner of the temporary file can write/delete it). This is an issue when running drush cron.

If I upload a file, and the file gets stored in /tmp, then the owner is _www (I'm on a MacOS machine). When I run drush, I'm running it as my own user, so if I run drush cron then my user is attempting to delete the temporary file(s) that was uploaded, and I get a permission denied.

Can anyone think of a simple workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Simply make CRON run drush as _www user. /etc/cron.d suppotys it, it's format is:

```
#<timing>   <user> <command>
```

Just make entry for your drush:

```
11 * * * *    _www   drush
```

Details, of course, may vary a little.

I used [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/170870).

Comment: This assumes he's not on shared hosting and his user account on the server has permissions to access crontab.

An alternative is to create a seperate `tmp` directory either within drupal root and limit it access via an .htaccess file. Or create a seperated /tmp directory elsewhere on the system, such as `/home/myuser/php-tmp/`. You can then set the location for this tmp folder in `admin/config/media/file-system`

Comment: @tenken if he is on shared hosting and he is using *_www* user & shared directory for temp files, then he already has a security hole to be measured in nautical miles, and DoSing him by competitors would be childish play... I haven't even considered that any hosting company would *allow* configuration like this. I sure hope no hosting company is so careless.